# Is it possible for the laravel web route file accessible in postman software

Tags: laravel

[image]

is it possible for the laravel web route file accessible in postman software

Comment: It should not be - that'd be a misconfiguration of your server - and accessing it directly won't do anything either. You'd just get an error.

Comment: @ceejayoz, if disable the csrf, then what will be the differences between api and web?

Comment: after disable  csrf its works for me. thanks

Comment: @sta I am confused. Who said anything about API vs. web or CSRF? How did you figure out OP's having issues with POST requests here?

Comment: @ceejayoz, op wants to access web routes (web.php) with postman api (except api.php).

Comment: @sta I'm impressed that you managed to decipher that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out of the box. One could create a route echoing the route file that you desire, but it's not something recommended and would make your application prone to security vulnerabilities.

If, on the other hand, what you need is the list of routes that you application has available, you can use the following command:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

- Make sure your terminal is placed within your project folder before running the command